Differential equation with step function
I want to solve the equations of motion for a system with a unit step function. Are there any methods that can be used to solve these? As a toy model, I picked a sliding mass bouncing off a spring.
The setup for the problem is:
$$mx''= -\Theta(x)kx \\ x(0)=u \qquad u > 0 \\ x'(0)=-v  \qquad v > 0$$
The non-linearity of the step function prevents the use of most methods to solve ODEs. However, the function can be transformed into linear regions.
Region 1: sliding freely towards the spring:
$$mx'' = 0, x(0)=u, x'(0)=-v $$
Region 2: in contact with the spring:
$$mx'' = -kx, x(T1)=0, x'(T)=-v$$
Region 3: sliding freely away from the spring:
$$mx'' = 0, x(T2)=0, x'(T2)=v$$
These are all solvable however for more complicated problems it will become difficult to predict what the future boundary conditions will be without iteratively solving through the regions before it (e.g. a second spring mirrored to this one would oscillate forever creating endless regions). At that point I may as well compute the solution numerically which I would like to avoid.
Are there any methods to solve differential equations with a step function that don't have this limitation?

the step function is more naturally handled using the theory of distributions, instead of regular functions.

See the 3blue1brown series on Differential Equations. In particular, this lesson talks about a step function. But what is a Fourier series? From heat flow to circle drawings
